How do I get acess to all animations in this .fbx file?
I downloaded this animation from sketchfab
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/rpg-7-animations-f2bef085e0164a34a4b090c73dcdc3f5
and there are multiple animations, but when I open it on blender, I get just one (Idle animation). How can I get the others animations? I went to Dopesheet -> Action Editor as suggested and see the name of the animations and can select then, but what is show still is the Idle animation. I'm using blender 2.8

Hello if this model is copyright free could you please share your file?

@moonboots hello, I uploaded on google drive, tell me if you can acess https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1r6cwQXpPXdijcS_DNqZP4S63l5xJQ5kG?usp=sharing

it asks for an authorization

Now anyone can acess it, if you can't, request acess and I will allow it, but you should be able to acess it now

I can see a whole list of actions in the dropdown menu of the Dope Sheet actually: https://zupimages.net/up/24/21/7w6g.jpg

I didn't know I had to click on 'Root' on the right side bar and then choose the root action. Well, I will try to import to unreal now, thank you for the reply
